# C language - Caesar Encryption Program

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

I want to make a program that takes letters and uses a Caesar encryption to shift them from a up 1 value to b. It must use a string in order to do this.

My problem is my program will not take the user's input into the string. (I attempted to put guy[10] in the scanf, but this only caused the program to crash-- so I willingly put the incorrect guy there so the program may compile).

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(){
int i=0; //setting the individual slot number for the array-- later used in the while loop
char guy[10];
printf("Enter Plain Text:");
scanf("%s",&guy); //takes user's input-- such as "abc" and puts it into its respective slot in the array guy[10] r-right?

while (guy[10] != '\0'){ //while loop that runs until it reaches the end of the string
    if ((guy[i]) >= 'A' && (guy[i]<= 'Z')){ //moves capital letter values up 1
        guy[i]=guy[i]++; //makes the current "slot" number go up 1 value. Example: a = 97 + 1 -> b = 98
        }
    if ((guy[i]) >= 'a' && (guy[i]) <= 'z'){// moves lower case letter values up 1
        guy[i]=guy[i]++;
    }
    i++; //moves the array's interval up to the next "slot"

}
printf("Encrypted text is: %s",guy);
}
```

Comment: Fyi, there are only so-many ways to reasonably implement Caesar ciphers in C, and `[c] Caesar` in the search box of this site will yield over a hundred of them.  Regarding your code. `guy[i]`, not `guy[10]`, should be in your while-condition expression. And `guy`, not `&guy`, should be the parameter passed to `scanf`.

Comment: while this is true, none of them cover C-language too in depth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first issue is this line:

```
scanf("%s",&guy);
```

as `guy` is an array so we don't need to get a pointer to it, it's name is treated as a pointer in this context.  Simply do:

```
(void) scanf("%s", guy);
```

Your second issue is this line:

```
while (guy[10] != '\0')
```

as WhozCraig noted int his comment -- this should use index `i`, not `10`

The third issue is that this statement makes little sense:

```
guy[i]=guy[i]++;
```

Reasonable alternatives include:

```
guy[i] = guy[i] + 1;
guy[i]++;
guy[i] += 1;
```

The fourth issue is you've not dealt with wrap-around.  E.g. what does 'Z' map to in your code?  It looks like it will come out as "[" instead of "A".

The fifth issue is that `scanf()` can overflow the array `guy` as it's input size is unlimited.  For `guy[10]`, we need to do something like:

```
scanf("%9s", guy);
```

To limit the input to nine characters with room for the final '\0'.  Using `fgets()` would be a better choice in this situation as it's safer and we don't need the parsing power of `scanf()`:

```
fgets(guy, 10, stdin);
```

Here's a rework that addresses these five issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char text[10];

    printf("Enter Plain Text: ");
    (void) fgets(text, 10, stdin); // takes user's input -- such as "abc" and put it into its respective slots in the array

    int i = 0; // slot index for the array

    while (text[i] != '\0') { // loop until reach end of string

        if (text[i] >= 'A' && text[i] <= 'Z') { // move capital letter values up 1
            // make the letter go up 1 modulo 26. Example: A = 65 + 1 -> B = 66; Z = 90 + 1 -> A = 65
            text[i] = ((text[i] - 'A' + 1) % ('Z' - 'A' + 1)) + 'A';
        } else if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i] <= 'z') { // move lower case letter values up 1
            text[i] = ((text[i] - 'a' + 1) % ('z' - 'a' + 1)) + 'a';
        }

        i++; // move the array's index up to the next "slot"
    }

    printf("Encrypted text is: %s\n", text);
}
```